# define enum class with same name compared to enum

Tags: c++11, enum-class

Why this compiles in c++11:

```
struct foo
{
  enum class Resolution { None=10, Nominal=20 };
  enum class Scale { None, Nominal };
};
```

while this doesn't:

```
struct foo
{
  enum Resolution { None=10, Nominal=20 };
  enum Scale { None, Nominal };
};
```

?

Comment: You don't need to put it inside of a struct to produce this ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before C++11 enum values were unscoped, meaning, that values in 2 enums can't be same.
This is no longer the case when using `enum class`.